# Firebase Bug: 3-way bound objects don't synchronize

Tags: html, angularjs, data-binding, ionic-framework, firebase

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/UwPmy7

Basically, I have a page in my Ionic app where I want users to be able to enter information into textboxes and then have that information synced to the firebase database based on their specific userID.

I have 2 factories which generate authentication tokens and firebase objects for user information respectively:

```
// Returns Firebase authenticator
.factory('Auth', ['$firebaseAuth',
    function($firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase('https://luminous-torch-5887.firebaseio.com/')

    return $firebaseAuth(ref);
    }
])

// Returns information for specified user's sale
.factory("UserSale", ["$firebaseObject",
    function($firebaseObject) {
        return function(userID) {
            var ref = new Firebase('https://luminous-torch-5887.firebaseio.com/users/');
            var userSale = ref.child(userID);

        return $firebaseObject(userSale);
        }
    }
]);
```

My controller for both the login and display tab begins with the generation of an Authentication token which is later used to login:

```
// Manages user-related information
.controller('AccountCtrl', ['$scope','Auth','$firebaseObject','UserSale',
    function($scope, Auth, $firebaseObject, UserSale) {

        // Create authenticator
        $scope.auth = Auth;

        // Set user's credentials when logged in
        $scope.auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
            $scope.authData = authData;
        });

    // More functions...
```

Here is my login function which is also used to 3-way-bind the user's data when they log in:

```
// AccountCtrl

$scope.authWithPassword = function() {
    Auth.$authWithPassword({

        // Retrieve user input
        email: $scope.email,
        password: $scope.password

    }).then(function(authData) {

        // When logged in, bind user data
        UserSale(authData.uid).$bindTo($scope, 'userSale');

        console.log('Logged in as: ' + authData.uid);

    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Authentication failed: ' + error);
    });
};
```

The data can then be modified in the HTML interface:

```
<ion-view view-title="Your Sale">
    <ion-content ng-controller="AccountCtrl">

        <!-- Show fields only when logged in -->
        <div ng-show="authData">

            <label class='item item-input'>
                <span class='input-label'>Title</span>
                <input type='text' ng-model='userSale.title'>
            </label>

            <label class='item item-input'>
                <span class='input-label'>Start Date</span>
                <input type='date' ng-model='userSale.startDate'>
            </label>

            <!-- More data fields -->
```

However, nothing seems to happen when I change the data in the fields. I know an object is being created and modified but it won't post changes to Firebase. I've tried using the .$save() operation as well but that doesn't seem to make a difference. I've also tried manually setting the data by using this command:

```
UserSale($scope.authData.uid).title = $scope.userSale.title;
```

But nothing ends up being written to the database.

Here are my Firebase security rules:

```
{
    "rules": {

        // Public read access
        ".read": true,

        // Users write to their own key
        "users": {
            "$uid": {
                ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested them through the simulator and everything works there. I also tried running it without security rules and that didn't seem to do anything either.

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: There's no need to initialize data. Your code looks correct. What do your security rules look like?

Comment: Updated with my security rules!

Comment: Is there an error in your console? Are you positive the user is authenticated? We may need to see your controller code.

Comment: I get these [errors](http://i.imgur.com/74J6lrm.jpg) every time I run the application but they haven't affected anything as far as I can tell. I'm almost positive the user is authenticated because the input fields only display when authentication data is present. I've edited my post adding more of my controller and factories.

Answer (score 0):

No, data doesn't need to be initialized before syncing data.

Have you tried seeing whether you have [logged onto firebase using command line](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiSrIaimKbLAhVL3GMKHVeVBFEQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.firebase.com%2Fdocs%2Fhosting%2Fcommand-line-tool.html&usg=AFQjCNHRooVVO4NcECZFGZsH1B7oo4NKwQ&sig2=1bgQBnYkh1CwHCYi7DFxQQ&bvm=bv.115339255,d.cGc)?

Your code, however, is correct, so I wouldn't worry about any conceptual errors.

Comment: I'm developing for mobile on Ionic so I'm not hosting. I've made sure that I've authenticated with Firebase before I attempt to access the data.